# Exception when Servlet try to run Hadoop 2.2.0 MapReduce Job

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, hadoop, wildfly

**SOLVED** (the solution is in the comments)

I'm using **Hadoop 2.2.0** (in pseudo-distributed mode) on ubuntu 13.10 and Eclipse Kepler v4.3 to develop my Hadoop program and **Dynamic Web Project** (without Maven).

My Hadoop jar project, called "WorkTest.jar", works correctly when I run job from command line with: "Hadoop jar WorkTest.jar" and I see correctly the work progress on the terminal.

Hadoop project contains four elements:

- DriverJob.java (class that configures and starts the job)
- Mapper.java
- Combiner.java
- Reducer.java

Now I have written a new Dynamic Web Project with a **ServletTest.java** in which I entered the DriverJob class code, the other class (Mapper.java, Combiner.java, Reducer.java) are placed in the same package as the servlet (main package). The WebContent/lib folder contains all Hadoop jar necessary dependencies.

I have successfully deploy my application on WildFly 8 Server whit Eclipse but when I try to run mapreduce job (the job configuration runs successfully and I managed to delete and write a folder on HDFS), he keeps on failing with the following exception visible from the Hadoop Job log file:

```
FATAL [IPC Server handler 5 on 46834] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1396015900746_0023_m_000002_0 - exited : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Mapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:721)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Mapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1718)
    ... 8 more
```

and from the WildFly log file:

```
WARN  [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter] Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
WARN  [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter] No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
```

But the WEB-INF/classes/ deploy folder on WildFly containing the Mapper.class, Combiner.class and Reducer.class.

I also tried to enter the class code of Mapper, Combiner and Reducer inside the servlet, but does not work with the same error...

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to have your `.class` files in an archive (jar) that can be distributed to the nodes in the cluster.

```
WARN  [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter] No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
```

This error is the key.  Generally you would use `job.setJarByClass(DriverJob.class)` to tell the mapreduce client which jar file has the Mapper/Reducer classes.  You don't have a jar and so that method for distributing the proper classes falls apart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed my approach: I have eliminated the DriverJob code from my ServletTest and put the Hadoop jar (WorkTest.jar) in the WEB-INF/lib folder. In my DriverJob.java I have set: 
`job.setJarByClass(jobexecutor.DriverJob.class);
job.setMapperClass(jobexecutor.Mapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(jobexecutor.Combiner.class);
job.setReducerClass(jobexecutor.Reducer.class);` 
Now I only call the DriverJob method `String output = jobexecutor.DriverJob.run(String inputData)` from servlet; but when I try to run mapreduce job he keeps on failing with the same exception...

Comment: I may have found the cause of the problem: if the inside of my DriverJob class I run the method `job.getJar();` this returns me a **null** value! Why?

Comment: And the mapper/reducer classes are in this `WorkTest.jar`?

Comment: Also, make sure there aren't any lingering instances of that class file somewhere in your classpath

Comment: Yes, the mapper/reducer classes are in `WorkTest.jar`. I managed to solve the problem by using `config.set("mapreduce.job.jar", "full_path_of_my_jobexecutor.jar_in_my_deploy_folder_on_wildfly");` within the `DriverJob.java`. The problem was that the method `job.setJarByClass(jobexecutor.DriverJob.class)` was not able to locate the package in which it is contained... I forced the declaration and the error is gone!